# How to get Facebook user details?

Tags: asp.net, facebook

I had developed my solution to get **Facebook** user details . the code worked with my account well but when i tried to test it by another account i doesn't get me any details.
I tied this solution with Facebook tab as when user click on tab it go to this solution .

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string host = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["host"];
    string facebookClientId =
      System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FacebookClientId"];
    string RedirectURL = "http://x.y.com";
    if (Request.QueryString["redirectURL"] != null)
    {
        RedirectURL = Request.QueryString["redirectURL"].ToString();
        Session["RedirectURL"] = RedirectURL;
    }
    Response.Redirect(@"https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=" +
      facebookClientId + "&redirect_uri=http://" + host +
      @"/FBcallback.aspx&scope=publish_stream,offline_access,publish_actions");

}
```

Comment: no error i told that i worked at my account but i doesn't work on other accounts

Answer (score 0):

Disable the `sandbox mode` from the App Settings.